# How to customize ORDER BY condition in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I want to order the output of the SPARQL queries not alphabetically, but in a  certain order that I define myself. I cannot find information on how to do it.

For example, I have a query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ?a ?b ?c
 WHERE { ... }
 ORDER BY ?c
```

The variable `c` can have a limited range of values: "s", "m", "m1", "m2", "p" and "w". 
I want the ordering to be as follows:

```
1) s
2) m
3) m1
4) m2
4) p
5) w
```

So, it is not an alphabetical order. 
How to force the ORDER BY to order output in this order?

I use SPARQL endpoint Fuseki to query a turtle file, and jinja2 templates to render the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *general*, you'd need to write a custom function, as described in [Jeen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28529770/1281433).  However, when you have a limited number of values, and you know the specific ordering, you can simply include a **values** block that associates each value with its sort index and then sort on that.  E.g., if you wanted to sort some sizes, you could do something like this:

```sql
select ?item where {
  values (?size ?size_) { ("small" 1) ("medium" 2) ("large" 3) }
  ?item :hasSize ?size 
}
order by ?size_
```

Comment: What if we have other values also? Can we put a regex there or do we need to write functions?

Comment: @bhargavrao that sounds like an interesting question. You could certainly do something with regexes and the ?size against a ?size_pattern or something. It's probably different enough that it merits a new question, though.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I had a submission tomo. So as a work around I ran a query enumerating all the other types in the triple store and used your method :D. But yep, I will ask a question bout that as soon as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve any custom sorting order by writing a custom function that implements the sorting logic and injecting that function into your SPARQL engine. See [this tutorial on how to create a custom function for the Sesame SPARQL engine](http://www.rivuli-development.com/further-reading/sesame-cookbook/creating-custom-sparql-functions/) - other SPARQL engines have similar functionality.

Once you have this function, you can use it in the ORDER BY argument:

```
SELECT ....
ORDER BY ex:customFunction(?c)
```

Comment: I don't use Sesame. I only use SPARQL endpoint Fuseki to get data from a turtle file and then render results in a jinja2 template.

Comment: Well you didn't mention that in your question, did you? Also: "*other SPARQL engines have similar functionality*"